# DataMapper - Set repository for many to many relationship using anonymous resource

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

I'm trying to migrate an old database using DataMapper and I am having an issue with a many to many relation.

I have a `Post` and `Tag` model that both go through an anonymous resource. I can set the repository name in the post and tag models, but not the auto-generated `PostTag` model (as far as I know). Is there a way to make all of them use the same repository name (`:legacy`)?

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a normal DM model for the "middle" resource to be able to define the repository name, such as

```
model PostTag
  include DataMapper::Resource
  def self.default_repository_name; :legacy end
  belongs_to :post, :key => true
  belongs_to :tag, :key => true
end
```

and in both of those parents, define the connection with a `:through`. For example,

```
model Post
  # other definitions ...
  has n, :post_tags
  has n, :tags, :through => :post_tags
end
```